# Knex: run $ npm install mysql2 --save Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: node.js, knex.js, mysql2

I'm trying to use `knex` CLI for implementing migrations for my local MySQL database in a Node.js ESM environment.

My `knexfile.js` file looks like this:

```js
import { DB_NAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_USER } from "../config/env.js";


/**
 * @type { Object.<string, import("knex").Knex.Config> }
 */
export default {
  development: {
    client: "mysql2",
    connection: {
      database: DB_NAME,
      user: DB_USER,
      password: DB_PASSWORD,
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10,
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: "knex_migrations",
    },
  },
};
```

I successfully created my first migration file with `knex migrate:make initial_schema --knexfile database/knexfile.js --esm` which I've been written my first user table:

```js
/**
 * @param { import("knex").Knex } knex
 * @returns { Promise<void> }
 */
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable("user", (table) => {
    table.increments("id").primary().unsigned().notNullable();
    table.string("profilname", 255).unique().notNullable();
    table.string("username", 255).unique().notNullable();
    table.string("password", 511).notNullable();
    table.timestamp("createdAt").notNullable().defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
    table
      .timestamp("updatedAt")
      .notNullable()
      .defaultTo(knex.raw("NOW() ON UPDATE NOW()"));
    table.datetime("lastLogin");
    table
      .enum("role", ["admin", "writer", "user"])
      .notNullable()
      .defaultTo("user");
  });
};

/**
 * @param { import("knex").Knex } knex
 * @returns { Promise<void> }
 */
exports.down = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists("user");
};
```

Until now everything works correctly. But when I run `knex migrate:latest --knexfile database/knexfile.js --esm` I get the error below:

```
> knex migrate:latest --knexfile database/knexfile.js --esm

Working directory changed to ~/PATH_TO_MY_LOCAL_DEV_FOLDER
Using environment: development
Knex: run
$ npm install mysql2 --save
Invalid or unexpected token
/LOCAL_ENV/node_modules/mysql2/node_modules/lru-cache/dist/cjs/index.js:781
                        this.#dispose?.(oldVal, k, 'set');
                                      ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
[...]
```

The `mysql2` package has already been installed. Moreover, I tried many times removing `node_modules` folder and reinstalling my dependencies in hope of resolving the issue.

Here is the most relevant part of my `package.json`:

```js
{
  [...]
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    [...]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dompurify": "^3.0.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "helmet": "^7.0.0",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "knex": "^3.0.1",
    "marked": "^9.0.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.3",
    "objection": "^3.1.2",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "zod": "^3.22.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    [...]
  }
}
```

In my opinion, the issue may be related to the fact that I use ESM. That is because I've tried to reproduce the error in a CommonJS module environment and no error had been thrown.

Comment: What _version_ of Node?

Comment: v18.16.0 and npm at 9.5.1

Comment: Same problem here, and also using ESM.

Comment: Did you get past this problem? Same problem here and using ESM.

Comment: No, I've rewrote all my import statements in a CommonJS way instead of ES. Honestly, If it's not restrictive for you to switch on CJS module, go on. Because, even if ESM can be used on a Node.js environment, try to avoid. There is also compatibility issues on other libraries regarding EcmaScript Modules.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to mysql2@2.3.3 finally got me past this problem. I suspect it is an issue with ESM.

You might keep your mysql2 client up to date by setting your package.json dependency to
`"mysql":"^2.3.3"`
so minor versions and patches come down, but keep you on version 2 to avoid this problem.